# "Migrations" ran out of gas after x blocks mainnet

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, out-of-gas, mainnet

I trying to deploy my contract but I cant. After deployed in ropsten and development, for some reason I can't deploy to mainnet.

Truffle v5.3.3 (core: 5.3.3)

deploying...

[image]

after

[image]

compilers

```
compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.8.0",
      // docker: true,
      settings: {
       optimizer: {
         enabled: true,
         runs: 1000
       },
      }
    }
  },
```

mainnet config

```
mainnet: {
        provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/xxxxx`),
        network_id: 1,
        gas: 5000000,
        gasPrice: 5e9,
        // confirmations: 2,
        from: 'xxx',
        // timeoutBlocks: 200,
        skipDryRun: true
    },
```

My question is: how much gas do I need to put and how many blocks will be counted to deploy? At 57 the truffles broke, how much do you need to deploy?

**EDIT**

I deploy to ropsten and works. But mainnet not.

[image]

Comment: Just deploy to a test chain (i.e local ganache) and check the report for "gas used" the OP_CODES have the same cost anyway, so you should set gas to that value or higher. For gas price, you can check it here (https://etherscan.io/gastracker) and choose the priority level that suits you best.

Comment: I edit question to show you ropsten works. I need to change "gas" or "gasPrice"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your gasPrice to be much higher. 1 Gwei is 1e9, and these days 60-100 gwei are "normal" gas prices. Often even more is needed. See [here](https://www.gasprice.io/) for current gas prices.